# jQuery's (deep) extends bug?

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm trying to deep copy an object using jQuery but it fails to provide a completely independent object.

Here's my code.

```
var copy = $.extend(true, {}, this);
```

Then when I compare the two objects, i get the following result:

- `copy == this` => **false** (so far so good)
- `copy.LstOptions == this.LstOptions` => **false** (so far so good)
- `copy.LstOptions[0] == this.LstOptions[0]` => **true** (**problem**)

`LstOptions` isn't a primitive type though, it's actually an array of object. Here's its content :

```
[{"ID":22,"Name":"man"},{"ID":27,"Name":"weird"},{"ID":25,"Name":"womanii"}]
```

How comes it doesn't get deep copied and how to have it deep copied?

Ps: here's my full boject:

```
{"changed":false,"data":null,"LstOptions":[{"ID":22,"Name":"man"},{"ID":27,"Name":"weird"},{"ID":25,"Name":"womanii"}],"NewRecord":null,"NewID":0,"done":false}
```

`this` also has a few methods (a constructor), no property (get/setters).

Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wk9e2kgn/1/ where console.log outputs `true` where I expect it to output `false`.

Comment: That's for objects, not for arrays. Just use json for your case. This is abuse in itself, extend is meant to extend prototypes.

Comment: jQuery's doc say that: "On a deep extend, Object and Array are extended, but object wrappers on primitive..."

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/o5hbd6f3/ Are you sure `LstOptions` contains what you think it does? (If the array is empty you're comparing undefined with undefined which is true.)

Comment: The JSON I pasted is a direct call to JSON.stringify(this) just after the call to var copy = $.extend(true, {}, this);

Comment: @simonzack how do you suggest I deep copy my object? Using $.extend is a most upvoted answer here on SO.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with an example that can reproduce the issue. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce the issue into a limited amount of code. I might eventually take the risk of giving a url to the whole website... but then how long before getting bullied for that?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wk9e2kgn/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't deep copy object's members which type are custom object.

The best work around might be to create a copy constructor.

EDIT:
I just added `this.constructor = Object.prototype.constructor;` at the end of my constructor which make jQuery's extend deep copy the object.

```
SpecialDataField.Options.Option = function (ref) {
    /**
    @type {int}
    */
    this.ID = 0;

    /**
    @type {?string}
    */
    this.Name = null;

    if (ref != null) {
        for (var v in this) {
            if (v in ref) {
                this[v] = ref[v];
            }
        }
    }

    this.constructor = Object.prototype.constructor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is working perfectly fine in your example. I have created a jsfiddle to show you that jquery is making a deep copy of your object using `$.extend`. I have also tested it by changing value original object's property but it did not affect the same property of copied object.

The code i have written for this is as below:

```
var original= {"changed":false,"data":null,"LstOptions":[{"ID":22,"Name":"man"},{"ID":27,"Name":"weird"},{"ID":25,"Name":"womanii"}],"NewRecord":null,"NewID":0,"done":false};

// deep copy
var copy = $.extend(true, {}, original);

// compare objects which results false
alert(original.LstOptions[0]==copy.LstOptions[0]);

// change value
original.LstOptions[0].Name="Ankush";

// check same property of both objects
alert(original.LstOptions[0].Name);
alert(copy.LstOptions[0].Name);
```

You can find [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8cuet2f/1/) here

Comment: Saying "your code works perfectly fine" doesn't help OP to solve their problem.

Comment: OP says that copy.LstOptions[0] == this.LstOptions[0]  this statement returns true but is is not like that, It returns false. And also i have explained my answer.